# Publishing npm private package to AWS CodeArtifact (private field set to true in package.json)

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, npm-publish, aws-codeartifact

## Context

I am attempting to publish a *private* package to AWS CodeArtifact and having difficulties.

The `package.json` file has its `private` field set to `false` to prevent accidental publishing to npmjs.com registry in case a developer in our team makes a mistake.
Package publish to AWS CA fails with the expected error (see Response 1 below).

Same thing happens when I specify the following `publishConfig` (see Response 2 below).

```json
{
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://xxxxx-demo-domain-xxxxxxxxxxxx.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/xxxxx-demo-repo/",
    "access": "restricted"
  }
}
```

## Question

How do I configure the `publishConfig` to allow the package to be published to a specific AWS CA domain/registry under our team control?
I couldn't find information about it in the AWS Documentation nor on StackOverflow nor anywhere else online.

### Response 1

```sh
$ npm publish
npm notice
npm notice   @ec/trivial-package@1.2.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 77B  index.js
npm notice 797B package.json
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          @ec/trivial-package
npm notice version:       1.2.0
npm notice filename:      @ec/trivial-package-1.2.0.tgz
npm notice package size:  541 B
npm notice unpacked size: 874 B
npm notice shasum:        a356f71ca997c48c54cd91172884ae8da9911725
npm notice integrity:     sha512-WSa7fmhfuSXFY[...]Nn9JqgAUaHSeA==
npm notice total files:   2
npm notice
npm ERR! code EPRIVATE
npm ERR! This package has been marked as private
npm ERR! Remove the 'private' field from the package.json to publish it.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\igors\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-06T01_47_28_986Z-debug.log
```

### Response 2

```sh
$ npm publish
npm notice
npm notice   @ec/trivial-package-2@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents ===
npm notice 77B  index.js
npm notice 609B package.json
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          @ec/trivial-package-2
npm notice version:       1.0.0
npm notice filename:      @ec/trivial-package-2-1.0.0.tgz
npm notice package size:  507 B
npm notice unpacked size: 686 B
npm notice shasum:        57511cd858f92a1818621045f34bfd5723649271
npm notice integrity:     sha512-uV5seBJT40fFy[...]BVD355OzLkcBQ==
npm notice total files:   2
npm notice
npm ERR! code EPRIVATE
npm ERR! This package has been marked as private
npm ERR! Remove the 'private' field from the package.json to publish it.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\igors\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-06T20_27_04_435Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Remove private?

Comment: @kichik why would I remove `private` if I want to prevent accidental publishing of the package to a public repository???

Comment: It prevents any publishing. Not just public.

Comment: @kichik I was under impression that you can configure an exception via `publishConfig`. Am I wrong?

Comment: The error you're getting and the documentation suggest it's either `private` or `publishConfig`, not both.